# Oracle BI 12c ,new repository not show in subject area after "RPD upload complete successfully" message

Tags: repository, oracle12c, oracle-bi, bi-tool

I used data-model-cmd.sh command to upload new RPD file and when i got "RPD upload complete successfully", there is no new repository in subject area in OBIEE 12c console on real time.

Some time I should refresh multiple time the page and restart or change my browser to show the new repository in subject area !!
And the other thing is when it shows in subject area, the older one is disappear, something like the new one overwrite the old one and I can't access to that.

Could you help me please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "feature" (bug) in most current 12c versions. You must include the -D flag at the end of your datamodel call.